# How to decode a large number from JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing, codable

How do I parse JSON like this:

```
let json = "{\"key\":18446744073709551616}"

struct Foo: Decodable {
    let key: UInt64
}

let coder = JSONDecoder()
let test = try! coder.decode(Foo.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

The problem is that that number is too big for `UInt64`. I know of no larger integer types in Swift.

```
Parsed JSON number <18446744073709551616> does not fit in UInt64
```

I wouldn't mind getting it as `String` or `Data`, but that's not allowed because `JSONDecoder` knows it's supposed to be a number:

```
Expected to decode String but found a number instead.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Decimal` instead:

```
let json = "{\"key\":184467440737095516160000001}"

struct Foo: Decodable {
    let key: Decimal
}

let coder = JSONDecoder()
let test = try! coder.decode(Foo.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(test) // Foo(key: 184467440737095516160000001)
```

`Decimal` is the Swift overlay type of [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber) which

> ... can represent any number that can be expressed as `mantissa x 10^exponent` where mantissa is a decimal integer up to 38 digits long, and exponent is an integer from –128 through 127.

You could also parse it as a `Double` if the full precision is not needed:

```
struct Foo: Decodable {
    let key: Double
}

let coder = JSONDecoder()
let test = try! coder.decode(Foo.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(test) // Foo(key: 1.8446744073709552e+36)
```

Comment: Thank you! And what if it's even larger? I don't think JSON specifies any limit on the size of numbers.

Comment: @Max: If the number has more than 38 decimal digits but fits into the range of a Decimal then this seems still to work, but the result loses precision. – I don't know of a way of handling even larger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the case that JSONDecoder is using NSDecimalNumber behind the scenes

```
struct Foo: Decodable {
    let key: Int
}

// this is 1 + the mantissa of NSDecimalNumber.maximum
let json = "{\"key\":340282366920938463463374607431768211456}"
let coder = JSONDecoder()
let test = try! coder.decode(Foo.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Even in the DecodingError, the number is not accurately represented:

```
Parsed JSON number <340282366920938463463374607431768211450> does not fit in Int.
```

So use `Decimal` if you want to be able to decode at maximum precision (though you still might silently lose precision). Otherwise you just need to yell at whoever is sending you that JSON.

---

Note that while the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber) says

> mantissa is a decimal integer up to 38 digits

It's actually a 128-bit unsigned integer, so it can represent some 39 digit numbers as well, as seen above.